# FIRDatabaseReference messagesQuery.queryEqualToValue return nothing

Tags: swift, firebase

I am using JSQMessagesViewController firechat

The following return null in snapshot

```
private func observeMessages() {

    let messagesQuery = messageRef.queryLimitedToLast(50)

    let query = messagesQuery.queryEqualToValue("100", childKey: "recipient")

    query.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

        let id = snapshot.value!["sender"] as! String
        let text = snapshot.value!["text"] as! String
        let recipient = snapshot.value!["recipient"] as! String
        self.addMessage(id, text: text, recipient:recipient)
        self.finishReceivingMessage()
    })
}
```

The following return data

```
private func observeMessages() {

    let messagesQuery = messageRef.queryLimitedToLast(50)

    messagesQuery.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

        let id = snapshot.value!["sender"] as! String
        let text = snapshot.value!["text"] as! String
        let recipient = snapshot.value!["recipient"] as! String
        self.addMessage(id, text: text, recipient:recipient)
        self.finishReceivingMessage()
    })
}
```

I need to filter by recipient and my firebase database tree is like below

[image]

I have been searching around google and SO here but just couldn't find any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a variant of `queryEqualToValue` that does not do what you want.

Instead use this:

```
let query = messagesQuery. queryOrderedByChild("recipient").queryEqualToValue("100")
```

Comment: You are my hero !